# Make button fit in responsive tailwindcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I'm using `tailwindcss` to make my css.
I'm struggling to make my buttons fit inside the screen on responsive. I would like it to split in 2 lines when the screen gets smaller.

This is what I've made for the moment.

```js
const displayAlphabet = () => {
        let res = []
        for (let i = 65; i < 91; i++) {
            res.push(
                <button key={i} className="font-bold text-saf-300 w-6" type="button" onClick={(e) => setSearchItem(e.target.value)} value={String.fromCharCode(i)}>{String.fromCharCode(i)}</button>
            )
        }
        res.push(<button type='button' onClick={(e) => setSearchItem("") } className="fas fa-undo text-saf-300"></button>)
        return res
    }

return (
<div className="min-h-screen mt-10">
    <div className="flex justify-center mb-10">
        <h1 className="uppercase font-bold text-saf-300 text-4xl">découvrez la liste des lots</h1>
    </div>
    <div className="flex ml-11 space-x-8">
        {displayAlphabet()}
    </div>
</div>
)
```

Actual rendering of issue

[image]

Comment: Edit, just add to remove the flex and it fits automatically.

Comment: Samuel, there's always gonna be a case where it's not gonna fit in one line. Rather than breaking into multiple lines, I would recommend to use `overflow-auto` property.